# Parameterized constructors of derived class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

There are two classes. One is derived from a base class. Both of these classes have parameterized constructors.

```
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

//declaring parent class
class parent
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    parent(int x);
    void displayx();
};

//declaring child class
class child:public parent
{
private:
    int b;
public:
    child(int y);
    void displayy();
};

//defining constructors and methods of parent class
parent::parent(int x)
{
    parent::a=x;
    std::cout<<"parent \n";

}
void parent::displayx()
{
    std::cout<<parent::a<<"\n";
}

//defining constructors and methods of child class
child::child(int y):parent(y)
{
    child::b=y;
    std::cout<<"child \n";
}

void child::displayy()
{
    std::cout<<child::b;
}

//main function
int main()
{
    child c1(10);// creating a child object
    //displaying values of int a and int b
    c1.displayx();
    c1.displayy();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the value 10 will be passed to both constructors when I create an object of the class child.I would like to know is there a way I can recode the above code where I can pass a different value
to the base class constructor whenever I create a child object and pass a value to its constructor.
For example:- I will create a child object and pass value 20 to its constructor but I want to pass value input by a user to the base class constructor so that int a and int b will have different values(I assume that the base class constructor is implicitly invoked whenever I create a child constructor)
Thank you!!

Comment: Something according to `child::child(int x, int y):parent(x), b(y)` maybe?!? I probably don't get your question ...

Comment: To save yourself from a lot of typing: Instead of `parent::a`, just say `a` when used in `parent` member functions. The constructor: `parent::parent(int x) : a(x) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of your `child` class can take two values - one for `a` and one for `b`, and you can pass the first one to the parent constructor:

```
class child : public parent
{
// ...
public:
    child(int x, int y);
// ...
};


child::child(int x, int y) : parent(x)
{
    b = y;
    std::cout << "child \n";
}

int main()
{
    child c1(20, 10);// creating a child object
    // ...
}
```

Also I think you meant to include `<iostream>` instead of `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Even better `: parent(x), b(y) {...`